# OpenCV 3.1 - Cannot find library of opencv_contrib

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I've installed OpenCV3.1 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu following this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/). For short, when building the library, I've passed this flag

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..`

Already passed the `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` flag. Then, I want to try the new `sfm` module from the `opencv_contrib` with `C++`, but got this error:

`` /tmp/ccHDBnbF.o: In function `main':
cam_motion.cpp:(.text+0x999): undefined reference to `cv::sfm::reconstruct(cv::_InputArray const&,  cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, bool)'
cam_motion.cpp:(.text+0xb5a): undefined reference to `cv::viz::Viz3d::Viz3d(cv::String const&)'
cam_motion.cpp:(.text+0xba7): undefined reference to  `cv::viz::Viz3d::setBackgroundColor(cv::viz::Color const&, cv::viz::Color const&)'
cam_motion.cpp:(.text+0xbc0): undefined reference to `cv::viz::Viz3d::registerKeyboardCallback(void     (*)(cv::viz::KeyboardEvent const&, void*), void*)'
cam_motion.cpp:(.text+0xe2c): undefined reference to `cv::viz::Viz3d::wasStopped() const'
cam_motion.cpp:(.text+0xeaf): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::eye(int, int, int)'
cam_motion.cpp:(.text+0xfd4): undefined reference to `cv::viz::WCube::WCube(cv::Point3_<double>     const&, cv::Point3_<double> const&, bool, cv::viz::Color const&)'
cam_motion.cpp:(.text+0x1001): undefined reference to `cv::viz::Widget::setRenderingProperty(int, double)' ``

I guess this is a linker problem.

What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you Download the OpenCV contrib package and place it in the specified location ? If not then download it from  [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)

Then Put it inside a specific folder and while compiling it with Cmake give the path(absolute path) till *modules* folder. And then try building it again.

If you still face any issues, comment the details about it.

Comment: I have used a similar way when installing the OpenCV into my Mac and also cannot find the correspondence library (like libopencv_viz). Will try again.

Comment: Solved the issue. Turns out, to use the SfM, I will need to build back the OpenCV with -D WITH_VTK=ON (of course with the vtk library installed in the system). Dependencies needed by the SfM also would be needed to be installed in the system too.